# How to add types for redux-form's Field wrapper

Tags: redux-form, flowtype

I have this component.

```
//@flow
import React from 'react'
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
import type { FieldProps } from 'redux-form';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'

const renderField= ({ input, label, disabled, meta: { touched, error } }: FieldProps) => {
  //component defn
}

export const InputField = (props) => {
  return (
    <Field
      {...props}
      component={renderField}
    />
  )
}
```

Input field accept all props what redux-form Field accept plus custom props. **The question is how to flowify my props for InputField?**
redux-forms index.js.flow exports types for renderField(FieldProps) but it doesn't export types for Field component. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.ElementProps` (`import type { ElementProps } from 'react'` or change your react import to `import * as React from 'react'`).

Then you can do something like:

```
type OGFieldProps = React.ElementProps<typeof Field>
type Props = $Diff<OGFieldProps, { component: $PropertyType<OGFieldProps, 'component'> }>
```

The reason I'm doing the diff is because otherwise you'll have to pass component, but since you're doing it in your `InputField` already, you probably don't want someone to pass one in thinking it's going to override.